# Is $\{1, \cos{x}, \sin{x} \}$ linearly independent in the vector space of mapping from $\{ k\pi : k \in \mathbb{N} \}$ to $ \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

Is $\{1, \cos{x}, \sin{x} \}$ linearly independent in the vector space of mapping from $(\{ k\pi : k \in \mathbb{N} \}, \mathbb{R})$ ?

---

To check if it is linearly independent, we must have that

$$a \cdot 1 + b \cdot \cos{x} + c \cdot \sin{x} = 0$$ implies that $a = b = c = 0$.

Let $x = 0:$
$$\implies a \cdot 1 + b \cdot \cos{0} + c \cdot \sin{0} = 0$$
$$a + b + 0 = 0 \implies a = - b$$

Let $x = \pi:$
$$\implies a \cdot 1 + b \cdot \cos{\pi} + c \cdot \sin{\pi} = 0$$
$$a - b + 0 = 0 \implies a = b$$

So we must have $a = b = 0$. Is that correct ?

We also know that $\sin{x} = 0$ for every $k\pi : k \in \mathbb{N}$, but in this case, the coefficient $c$ doesn't necessarily have to be zero, does it ?

Comment: You are right, they are not linearly independent.

Comment: Yes, $\sin x$ in this vector space is just zero vector, and any set that includes zero vector is linearly dependent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that the three are not linearly independent, for the simple reason that one of them is the zero vector.

1. Any finite set $S=\{s_1, s_2,\dots, s_n, 0\}$ containing the zero vector must be linearly dependent, since $1\cdot 0 + 0\cdot s_1 + 0\cdot s_2+\cdots 0\cdot s_n = 0$.
2. Since $\sin{k\pi} = 0$ for all $k\in\mathbb Z$, it is clear that for any mapping $f$ from $\{k\pi, k\in\mathbb N\}$ to $\mathbb R$, we have $(f+\sin)(x) = f(x)+\sin(x) = f(x)+0=0$, which means that $\sin x$ is indeed the zero vector of your vector space.

Comment: Asking just out of curiosity that *range of $\{1, \cos{x}, \sin{x}\}$ is $\{1, \pm 1, 0\}$ for $x=k \pi$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}$* is linearly dependent. RIght?

Comment: @LuckyChouhan Yes.